# salesforce database integration

Tags: integration, database-connection, salesforce

I am looking to create a connection from salesforce to a sql 2000 database.  I need to be able to transfer data from salesforce to sql 2000 and from sql 2000 back to salesforce.  An example of what I want to do is if a user creates a new calendar event in salesforce I want to be able to send that event to my sql 2000 database so that I can create a meeting record.  Then I want to pass back the unique id from sql to salesforce so that the records in both systems will be connected.

How do I create that connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build it yourself, then you can use the replication api (see the getUpdated/getDeleted API calls) to poll for data changes in salesforce.com and/or use outbound messaging to get HTTP notifications of data changes triggered by workflow. The create/update/delete api calls can be used to push data into salesforce.com. You'll probably want to start by reading the [web services api docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) first.

If you don't want to build it, then there a number of applications available to do this, including ForceAmp and Relational Junction, see the [AppExchange](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/) for more ideas.

Comment: Superfell thank you for your help.  The API and outbound messaging is what I needed to move forward on my project.